# VHDL: Mapping a slice of an output to a signal

Tags: vhdl, aggregate

I want to map the lower bit (bit0) of a 32 bit output port to a signal and leave the upper bits unconnected (OPEN). Is there a way to treat this mapping as an aggregate?

I've tried the following to no avail:
port map (
                 some_output    =>     ( 0 => sig_1, others => OPEN)
         );

Comment: A similar question was asked on the ghdl discussion list yesterday. From the LRM - "It is an error if an actual of open is associated with a formal that is associated individually. An actual of open counts as the single association allowed for the corresponding formal but does not supply a constant, signal, or variable (as is appropriate to the object class of the formal) to the formal." So you're left with declaring a dummy signal to connect the unused elements in independent association or not using them in a signal with the same index range.

Answer (score 4):

The below is not a valid answer, since it does not adhere to the VHDL standard.  This "answer" is however kept here, and not deleted, since it shows what construction to avoid for tool compliance, since some tools apparently accept this non-standard compliant VHDL code.

Example of port mapping without association of all scalar subelement, which is accepted by Altera Quartus II and Mentor ModelSim in some cases, but is also likely to result in warning or error:

```
port map(
  some_output(0) => sig_1,
  -- some_output others are simply not included in port mapping
```

So, as David Koontzs point out in the comment, the VHDL standard (IEEE Std 1076-2008) section "6.5.7 Association lists" describes:

> ... every scalar subelement of the explicitly declared interface object shall be associated exactly once with an actual (or subelement thereof) in the same association list, and all such associations shall appear in a contiguous sequence within that association list. Each association element that associates a slice or subelement (or slice thereof) of an interface object shall identify the formal with a locally static name.

So it is not valid to only associate some of the scalar subelements, since the standard says "every scalar subelement", and `open` can't be used for the remaining scalar subelements, since the standard says "Each association element that associates a slice ... of an interface object shall identify the formal with a locally static name.".

Comment: I don't think this solution will work. If you want to assign a slice of the output to a signal, you need to map the output to a signal of the same width as the output and then assign a signal to a slice of said.

Comment: @outer08 The solution from Morten is working, at least in my tools chains :) What you can't to is something like `some_output(0) => sig_1,` `some_output(7 downto 1) => open`

Comment: vcom-1193) Formal "some_output" length is 32; number of individual associations is 1.

Comment: @outer08: You are right; I can reproduce this error in ModelSim 10.1e and 10.3c.  The error only occurs if the length of `some_output` is given by a literal, but not when given by a generic value, which is why I did not see the error before posting the answer.

Comment: And this doesn't match the LRM either, "Furthermore, every scalar subelement of the explicitly declared interface object shall be associated exactly once with an actual (or subelement thereof) in the same association list, and all such associations shall appear in a contiguous sequence within that association list. "  You have the rest of the sub elements missing.  Shall is imperative in the standard. See  Paragraph 16 IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.7.1 Association lists, General (the same holds true in -1993, 4.3.2.2, "must" instead of "shall", still imperative).  It's the 'every' at issue.

Comment: @DavidKoontz: Thanks for pointing to that place in the standard, and I have updated the "answer" accordingly.  Related to this, next std. section says:  "If an interface element in an interface list includes a default expression for a formal generic constant, for a formal port of any mode other than linkage, ... then any corresponding association list need not include an association element for that interface element."  Doesn't that implicate that even port with `out` mode must have a default expression for the formal, if that port is to be omitted in the association list ?

Comment: It was Tristan on ghdl-discuss, yesterday. I just pointed out the bit saying you couldn't use open except on the entire thing. Re your quotes from next *paragraph*, I don't see anything there requiring a default expression for a formal. Also see 6.5.6.3 Port clauses, last para. It's only an error when a port formal of mode in without a default expression is unconnected. Also last sentence "It is an error if some of the subelements of a composite formal port are connected and others are either unconnected or unassociated."

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification; I found 6.5.6.3 Port clauses, last para, and can see the point.

Comment: +1 for the "contiguous sequence" bit for VHDL2008 - I just got bit by that bug.  Seemed so much more intuitive to try to group the signals the other way, by component...

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is this:

```
signal my_vector       : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
signal my_vector_float : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);

port map (
  [...]
  some_output(3 downto 0) => my_vector,
  some_output(7 downto 4) => my_vector_float,
  [...]
);
```

You can now setup some report filter rules to silence all warning concerning `*_float` signals.